# Replacing values in list of list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists containing random values, for instance

```
[[1,2,3],
 [2,3,1],
 [3,2,3]]
```

I would like to go through the list, and replace every type of value, lets say 1, with a letter "a", and the remaining values with another letter, lets say "b". How can I do this in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Double comprehension `[[... for x in ...] for y in ...]` with an `... if ... else ...` expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Hi @Snadder, and welcome to stackoverflow. Yoy may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question a little bit. More precisely, you may want to show you have tried something, and the result. And, at the very least, you may want to pin down the question to say: 'this is what I would want as a result'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't show any effort at solving a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
lst = [[1,2,3], [2,3,1], [3,2,3]]

print([['a' if y == 1 else 'b' for y in x] for x in lst])
# [['a', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b']]
```