# How to replace list of list in python

Tags: python

I have this list of lists`

```
listoflist = [[['I', 'nvestment activity during the year is summarised as fol', 'l', 'ows:'],
              ['InterFace-Light', 'InterFace-Light', 'InterFace-Light', 'InterFace-Light'], 
              [[9.0], [9.0], [9.0], [9.0]]], 
              [(45.40929412841797, 167.94473266601562, 49.90929412841797, 178.0337371826172), 
               (47.360496520996094, 167.94473266601562, 241.59832763671875, 178.0337371826172), 
               (238.8065185546875, 167.94473266601562, 243.3065185546875, 178.0337371826172), 
               (240.51470947265625, 167.94473266601562, 259.0223083496094, 178.0337371826172)]]

              [[['Cost'], 
               ['InterFace-Bold'],
               [[9.0]]], 
               [(526.6923828125, 189.15679931640625, 544.8453979492188, 199.52481079101562)]]

              [[['Additions', '£’', '000'], ['InterFace-Bold', 'InterFace-Bold', 'InterFace-Bold'], 
               [[9.0], [9.0], [9.0]]], 
               [(56.747901916503906, 199.1571044921875, 95.19589233398438, 209.52511596679688), 
                (523.3358154296875, 199.1571044921875, 532.69580078125, 209.52511596679688), 
                (530.2658081054688, 199.1571044921875, 544.8457641601562, 209.52511596679688)]]]
```

I want to replace `listoflist[0][0][0]`with `['Investment activity during the year is summarised as follows:'], ['Cost'], ['Additions', '£’000']`

Here is is my current code:

```
new_list = [['Investment activity during the year is summarised as follows:'],
            ['Cost'],
            ['Additions', '£’000']]

for i in listoflist:
    i[0].pop(0)
    for ii in new_list:
       i[0].insert(0, ii)
```

[Replacing values in list of list Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872092/replacing-values-in-list-of-list-python) didn't help

Comment: You can directly use Python to replace a list item, like this: list[index][index][index] = content. Does that help?

Comment: do you want to "replace", meaning substitute the first element or "insert" meaning put something before the first element while keeping the first element?

Comment: just a little tip here , pop will return the element it pops. So you can try to use it. Or construct your need, concatenate the list and then affect it to the list element as said by @ChrisvandenHoorn

Comment: I want to replace the elements with the ones on the new_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do (replace or insert), here are two options:
To insert:

```
for ls in listoflist:
    ls.insert(0, "Investment activity during the year is summarised as follows:")
```

To replace:

```
for ls in listoflist:
    ls[0] = "Investment activity during the year is summarised as follows:"
```

edit:
replace:

```
listoflist[0][0] = "value1"
listoflist[1][0] = "value2"
listoflist[2][0] = "value3"
```

insert:

```
listoflist[0].insert(0, "value1")
```

edit2: I think I finally understood what you wanted to do:

```
for ls in listoflist:
    if ls[0] == ["I", "nvestment activity during the year is summarised as fol", "l", "ows:"]:
        ls[0] = new_list[0]
    elif ls[0][0] == ["Cost"]:
        ls[0] = new_list[1]
    elif ls[0][0] == ["Additions", "£’", "000"]:
        ls[0] = new_list[2]
```

Comment: nice. but this works for one list. I also want the replace the others with different value as in new_list

Comment: In that case you can use:  

listoflist[0][0] = "value1"
listoflist[1][0] = "value2"
listoflist[2][0] = "value3"

or listoflist[0].insert(0, "value1"), etc.

Comment: OK. can you use for loop?.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jonathan. please can you make the answer to generalize, so that I don't have to type in the values manually.(ie. loop through them)